# Script to watch for file changes & if detected, backup the original first.

Tags: shell, file, powershell, vbscript

As per the title I'm looking for a way to backup files (SQL queries to be specific) when they are saved over/replaced.

This is to prevent accidental saving without a decent fall back.

I think that using a combination of Powershell and .NET FileSystemWatcher might be a good combo and instead of an alert I could take the original and append datetime to it in another location.

(https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b)

So my question is, how to interrupt that save process within Windows and copy the file out before it's saved over?

I'm thinking it might not be possible without calling the PS when a save is initiated on that specific directory.

I have access to PS, VBS and elevated cmd.

TIA for any pointers or further reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to backup/save the previous before a newer version overwrites it as there are no OnBefore*X* events in the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher_events(v=vs.110).aspx).

- Changed: Occurs when a file or directory in the specified Path is changed.
- Created: Occurs when a file or directory in the specified Path is created.
- Deleted: Occurs when a file or directory in the specified Path is deleted.
- Disposed: Occurs when the component is disposed by a call to the Dispose method. (Inherited from Component.)
- Error: Occurs when the instance of FileSystemWatcher is unable to continue monitoring changes or when the internal buffer overflows.
- Renamed: Occurs when a file or directory in the specified Path is renamed.

The only way to do this would be to perform an initial back up of all the files. Then backup, with a timestamp pre/suffix, after each `Changed` event.

Comment: Thought it was a bit far fetched but many thanks for the explanation!

I see what you mean and that process would work just as well as there'd be a constant chain of revised editions. 

Cheers Spud!